# Partially Empty Response While Using Alamofire and SkyScanner When Updating to Swift 3

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, skyscanner

I am updating an app to Swift 3 and having some trouble with Alamofire and .get requests. Using the code below, I am making a .get requests to obtain flight data from SkyScanner's api. For whatever reason, the return JSON value from the final .get requests always returns partially empty. I get a successful message that the updates are complete, and a couple of the elements contain the correct data, but others like the itinerary information and carrier information are always empty.

I have tried changing the type of response (JSON, String, Data, etc.) but that doesn't seem to fix things. This code worked fine in Swift 2, its only with the recent update that everything broke. Any ideas as to what could be causing a partially empty JSON response?

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var key = "prtl6749387986743898559646983194"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getFlights()
}

func getSessionKey(destination: String, outboundDate: String, inboundDate: String, adults: Int, complete: @escaping(_ key: String?, _ error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    // Use the mandatory headers listed on the SkyScanner api page http://business.skyscanner.net/portal/en-GB/Documentation/FlightsLivePricingList
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Accept":"application/json"
    ]

    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "apiKey":key,
        "country":"US",
        "currency":"USD",
        "locationSchema":"iata",
        "locale":"EN",
        "originplace":"DUB",
        "destinationplace":"LON",
        "outbounddate":"2017-03-12",
        "inbounddate":"2017-03-20",
        "adults":1,
        "groupPricing":true
    ]

    // First get the session URL key so we can being the poll
    let sessionURL = "http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/v1.0"
    let sessionPost = Alamofire.request(sessionURL, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)
    sessionPost.responseString { (sessionResponse) in

        switch sessionResponse.result {
        case .success:
            if let responseHeader = sessionResponse.response?.allHeaderFields {

                // Get the session poll URL from the location header
                let locationHeader = responseHeader["Location"] as? String
                if let range = locationHeader?.range(of: "v1.0/") {
                    let sessionKey = locationHeader?.substring(from: range.upperBound)
                    complete(sessionKey, nil)
                }
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            complete(nil, error as NSError?)
        }
    }
}

func poll(sessionKey: String, complete: @escaping(_ data: JSON?, _ error: NSError?) -> Void) {

    // Take the new found session key and plug it into the poll func
    let pollingParameters: Parameters = [
        "sortype":"price",
        "sortorder":"asc",
        "includeQuery": false,
        "stops": 2,
        "includeCurrencyLookup": false,
        "includeBookingDetailsLink": true
    ]

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Accept":"application/json"
    ]

    // **PROBLEM HERE AS THE RETURNED VALUE ALWAYS CONTAINS SOME EMPTY ELEMENTS FOR AN UNDETERMINED REASON**
    let pollURL = "http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/v1.0/\(sessionKey)?apiKey=\(key)"

    let sessionPoll = Alamofire.request(pollURL, method: .get, parameters: pollingParameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers)

    sessionPoll.responseJSON(queue: DispatchQueue.global() ,completionHandler: { (response) in
        print(response.response?.statusCode ?? "There is no response")
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            if let value = response.result.value {
                //print("RawValue: \(value)")
                complete(JSON(value), nil)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            complete(nil, error as NSError?)
        }
    })
}

func beginPolling(sessionKey: String, complete: @escaping (_ itineraries: [String:[[String:JSON]]]?, _ error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    self.poll(sessionKey: sessionKey) { (data, error) in
        if error == nil {
            if data?["Status"].stringValue == "UpdatesPending"{
                let when = DispatchTime.now() + 1
                DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: {
                    print("Updates Pending")
                    self.beginPolling(sessionKey: sessionKey, complete: { (trips, error) in
                        complete(trips, error)
                    })
                })
            }else if data?["Status"].stringValue == "UpdatesComplete" {
                print("Updates Complete: \(data)")

            }else {
                // There is no Status and we've probably errored out somewhere
            }
        }else{
            // Error
        }
    }
}

func getFlights() {

    getSessionKey(destination: "LON", outboundDate: "2017-03-12", inboundDate: "2017-03-20", adults: 1) { (sessionKey, error) in
        if error == nil{
            let when = DispatchTime.now() + 1
            DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: {

                self.beginPolling(sessionKey: sessionKey!, complete: { (trips, error) in
                    if error == nil {
                        // Take the valid data and pass it on to the next viewcontroller
                    }else{
                        // Error
                    }
                })
            })
        }else {
            print("There has been an Error getting the session key")
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The api documentation changed without anyone noticing. The "stops" parameter only accepts values of 0 or 1 and any other input causes the strange outputs we have been seeing.